# Form Submit Button Hover Effect Not Showing

Tags: forms, html, css, hover

I have a submission button for a form.  I use a sprite as the background, and so on hover I shift the background over the width of my button to get the hover effect.  However, this is not working.

This is my html:

```
<form class="a">
<All the other Fields...>
<p><input type="submit" value="Submit"/><p>
</form>
```

And my css:

```
.a input[type="submit"] {
    margin-top: 15px;
    background: url(btn.png) no-repeat;
    width: 108px;
    height: 42px;
    border: none;
    color: transparent;
    font-size: 0;
}

.a input[type="submit"]:hover {
    background: url(btn.png) no-repeat 109 0;
}
```

Comment: Is the path to your background image correct?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
.a input[type="submit"]:hover {
    background: url('btn.png') no-repeat 109px 0px; /*use 109px   */
}
```

**and check your background image path.**

Answer (score 1):

Background-position: `for x:  %|px|left|center|right` and `for y  %|px|top|center|bottom`

It could be

```
.a input[type="submit"]:hover {
    background: url(btn.png) no-repeat;
    background-position: 109px 0px; // left 109px, top 0px
}
```

Or

```
.a input[type="submit"]:hover {
    background: url(btn.png) no-repeat 109px 0px;
}
```

Also make sure your `image` path is right. Right now your image should be at the same folder where your `css` is, according to `url(btn.png)`.

Answer (score 0):

You're missing `px` on your position. See [this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/5afGb/) for a working example